# Finding $(x,y)$ so that $3^{2x} + y \equiv 0 \bmod 10$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

**Prior information:**

$y = 2021k + 7$

$x = 1442k + 5$

**My solution:**

I started from

$3^{2x} + y \equiv 0 \bmod 10$.

Calculated and simplified until I found this $-(1)^{k} + k + 7 \equiv 0 \bmod 10$.

So $k = 10a + 4$ and then we put it in the original $(x,y)$ to find the solutions where $a$ is an integer

However, the book didn't find this. The book's solution was $k = 20a + 4$ where $a$ is an integer and $k = 20b + 14$ where $b$ is an integer.

Which one is correct? Can anybody please explain to me?

Comment: I suspect that the intent of the problem composer was to represent a solution that *generalizes well*.  The current problem involved $\pmod{10} = \pmod{2 \times 5}.$  I suspect that the problem composer is attempting to stretch your intuition into realizing that in general, for a problem involving $\pmod{n}$, if all else fails, the first step would be to obtain the prime factorization of $$n = p_1^{a_1} \times p_2^{a_2} \times \cdots \times p_r^{a_r}.$$  Then, you attack the underlying problem by attacking the $r$ problems involving $\pmod{p_k^{a_k}}$ separately.

Comment: They're equivalent: $\,\overbrace{4+10\:\!\color{#c00}N = 4+10(\color{#c00}{{\{0,1\}\!+\!2j}})}^{\textstyle\color{#c00}{N\,\equiv\, 0,1\pmod{\!2}}} = 4+\{0,10\}+20j \equiv 4,14 \pmod{\!20}.\,$ Without seeing the text we can't say why they worked mod $20$, but perhaps they scaled a congruence by $\,2\,$ at some point so ended up solving $\,2k\equiv 8\pmod{\!20}.\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your solution and the book's solution result in the same set of values. Consider your result to be $k = 10c + 4$ instead to avoid confusion with the variable names. With $c$ being even, i.e., $c = 2a$, this results in $10(2a) + 4 = 20a + 4$. On the other hand, with $c$ being odd, i.e., $c = 2b + 1$, this results in $10(2b + 1) + 4 = 20b + 14$. Another way to state this is $k \equiv 4 \pmod{10} \iff k \equiv 4 \pmod{20} \lor k \equiv 14 \pmod{20}$.

It's not clear to me why the book split the set of solutions into $2$ groups instead of just one simpler group like yours. A possible reason is that the method they used resulted in the separate solutions, with it not being noticed that they may be combined into just one solution.